# Proper understanding of "What Derrida thinks is impossible" sentence

Tags: grammar

I am very confused about understanding that sentence: "what Derrida thinks is impossible". It seems to me:

> "What Derrida thinks" + "is impossible" (It is impossible)

but it is:

> "What Derrida thinks is impossible" (It is what Derrida thinks as impossible)

I tried to transform it into question form to attempt to clearify its structure:

> "What is it Derrida thinks AS impossible?"

looks ok, but still I am confused to handle the sentence.

**How to decompose it into grammatic elements?**

*BTW: Full sentence is "Yet this is precisely what Derrida thinks is impossible, since his ontology rules out the possibility of anything existing in isolation from anything else at all."*

Comment: You want to reorder things? Derrida thinks **this** is impossible.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: *That Derrida thinks **that** is impossible!* I know how he thinks, so I know he would ***never*** think that!

Comment: Digerkam - your cited full sentence means *Yet this is precisely **the thing which Derrida thinks is impossible...***

Comment: If it's a full sentence, then it means "Derrida's thoughts are impossible". If it's a noun clause, then it means "The thing that Derrida considers to be impossible...". So, if you give it to us in a complete sentence, we'll be able to tell. Just as words on their own with no context, it's ambiguous. I think this question should be closed for lack of clarity, but I don't want to use my mod hammer on it

Comment: Would it help to replace "thinks is" with "considers"?